# Image to byte array from a url

Tags: c#

I have a hyperlink which has a image.

I need to read/load the image from that hyperlink and assign it to a byte array (`byte[]`) in C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

[`WebClient.DownloadData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddata) is the easiest way.

```
string someUrl = "http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png"; 
using (var webClient = new WebClient()) { 
    byte[] imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(someUrl);
}
```

Comment: WebClient is now obsolete. See the HttpClient version in @Dunc's answer for modern alternative.

Answer (score 14):

If you need an asynchronous version:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    {
        byte[] imageBytes =
            await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

.NET 4.5 introduced [WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddatataskasync) for async usage.

Example:

```
using ( WebClient client = new WebClient() )
{
  byte[] bytes = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync( "https://someimage.jpg" );
}
```