# How I can save url image to database as a jpg file using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using an ASP.NET MVC project. I'm trying to pass URL image to controller and want to save the image into database - not the image URL.

Comment: And exactly what is your question?  What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can download the image from the url and convert that to byte array , as you can see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599686/image-to-byte-array-from-a-url)

After that you save the byteArray in your database.

If you want to read the image you can encode the bytes in base64 and send to the view.

`return "image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);`

Answer (score -1):

In case of you have used **HttpPostedFileBase** object to get an image, then you should convert Image to byte Array and then you need to save that array to database rather than save URL directly.

You can see below code for the same.

```
public byte[] ConvertImageToByte(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    byte[] imageByte = null;
    BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
    imageByte = rdr.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);
    return imageByte;
}
```