# How to fix color c# DownloadData to byte array

Tags: c#

I am trying to download images (jpg, jpeg and png). But when the size exceeds 200,000 bytes, I'm getting a black and white picture.

My code:

```
byte[] fileBytes;
try 
{ 
   path = url + path; 
   fileBytes = (new WebClient()).DownloadData(path); 
}
catch
{
   path = urlNoimagefound;
   fileBytes = (new WebClient()).DownloadData(path);
}
... 
// and then I add byte in rdlc
```

I think I'm getting a black and white picture because of the size of the byte array.

How to fix that?

Thank you.

Comment: are you getting some kind of exception?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more? what is exception?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_exceptions.php

Comment: Sorry, My bad, I have exception of path. I was edit on this post.

Comment: if it reaches the `catch` method, then you should let it make an exception through  `catch (Exception ex)`, then once you're in the catch section, the `ex` will have the error data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do with DownloadData, but here is a snippet I use in an old project:

```
private static Image DownloadImage(string source)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    using (var stream = webClient.OpenRead(source))
    {
        return Image.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: DownloadData I do like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599708/12057519